# How to save historical data in sql when the data in the source changes in time

Tags: mysql, sql-server

My problem is that i have to get historical data about the revenue of my company, but item pricing change over time (let's say monthly), so our team replaces pricing rules in the database.

How can I save each month applicable pricing rules without making a monthly table with the pricing rules of the month. (thousands of data, so a table per month would be ridiculous).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is you didn't actually ask a question. There is nowhere near enough information here for anybody to be able to help. This would be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ You might also decide on which DBMS you are using. sql server <> mysql.

Comment: __"How can I save each month applicable pricing rules"__ - this is the answer. You have to save each month applicable pricing rules. So you have to make a table 'cause otherwise you'll not be able to save anything. You can't save it in the air.

Answer (score 1):

You should do exactly what you said you don't want to do - save all of the older versions of pricing rules.

I know you seem to think it would be a "ridiculous" amount of data, but mysql can handle a few hundred thousand lines in a table without much difficulty.